# Silverlight 4 Toolkit not appearing after install in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-2010, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-toolkit

I am running Visual Studio 2010 and have installed the Silverlight 4 Toolkit, however on creating a Silverlight Application I don't seem to have the controls in my Toolkit?

Can someone please help me on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They should install automatically to the ToolBox using the installer.  Verify that you are using the latest version of the toolkit and not using the Silverlight 3 version.

Also verify that you actually have a xaml file open in the designer.

If it is still not working, you can add them manually by:

1. Right-clicking on the ToolBox and select 'Choose items...'.
2. A dialog appears and you need to go to the 'Silverlight Components' tab.
3. Then click `Browse...`.  Navigate to folder whwere the toolkit is installed eg, `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Silverlight\v4.0\Toolkit\{release month year}\Bin`.
4. Select the DLL containing the controls you need.
5. Check all controls you want.
6. Repeat for all other controls.

Comment: thanks for prompt response. I don't have a Toolkit folder after installion?

Comment: @David then you are not installing it correctly. Download the MSI at: http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/43528 Run the MSI and all should be good.  If not post what error you are getting on install.

Comment: thanks a million, that solved me problem. Must have been installing something else (Silverlight4_Tools.exe)??? Thanks again.